# C# and Microsoft Speech.Recognition and Speech.Synthesis

Tags: c#, speech-synthesis

I'm new to C# and I'm new to Speech.Recognition.
I searched very long for tutorials but didn't find that much, I'm even not quiet sure whether I included everything correctly.

I downloaded:

- [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b1604d3-4f66-4241-9a21-90a294a5c9a4&displaylang=en)
- [Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb0f72cb-b86b-46d1-bf06-665895a313c7&displaylang=en)
- [Languages](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=47ffd4e5-e682-4228-8058-dd895252a3c3&displaylang=en)

I'm programming local, I have Windows XP, .net framework 3.5.

Now I just want to get started with some simple lines of code, like to say "hello world" or say one or two words as input.

I tried following, and of course it doesn't work :>
error:

> "The Typ- or Namespacename "SpeechSynthesizer" couldn't be found (Is a Using-Direktive or a Assemblyverweis missing?)"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace System.Speech.Recognition { }
namespace System.Speech.AudioFormat {}
namespace System.Speech.Recognition.SrgsGrammar{}
namespace System.Speech.Synthesis { }
namespace System.Speech.Synthesis.TtsEngine { }

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer foo = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            foo.Speak("Test");  
        }
    }
}
```

edit:

hello,
i tried you code,but 
using SpeechLib; 
couldn't be found :>

well now i wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.SpeechLib;

namespace System.SpeechLib { }
namespace System.Speech.Recognition { }
namespace System.Speech.AudioFormat {}
namespace System.Speech.Recognition.SrgsGrammar{}
namespace System.Speech.Synthesis { }
namespace System.Speech.Synthesis.TtsEngine { }
```

but I get an error with:

> numericUpDown1,SpVoice,SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags,textBox1 and Timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project + Add Reference, .NET tab, select "System.Speech".

A project template pre-selects several .NET assemblies.  But only common ones, like System.dll, System.Core.dll, etcetera.  You have to add the 'unusual' ones yourself.

Comment: +1. 
`Using` is just creating shortcuts to the namespaces. To use them you need to link assemblies to the project.

Comment: thank you, i took system.speech and now it works! greate - ( do you know how i switch to the german language?)

Comment: Yes, three years of German in high school helped.  But I don't think you'll get it on a Windows machine unless the Windows version is German.  Not sure what is required, money no doubt.  Start another question about that at superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

get `Interop.SpeechLib.dll`

```
using SpeechLib;

private void ReadText(string readText)
        {
            int iCounter = 0;
            while (Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value) > iCounter)
            {
                SpVoice spVoice = new SpVoice();
                spVoice.Speak(textBox1.Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak);
                spVoice.WaitUntilDone(Timeout.Infinite);
                iCounter = iCounter + 1;
            }
        }
```